# ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION permission

Tags: android, gps, android-permissions

I'm litte ashamed. But cant find what's wrong.

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.szymon.gpslab1"
android:versionCode="15"
android:versionName="4.0.3">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
</manifest>
```

It's my manifest.
and here's my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
LocationManager locationManager;
LocationListener locationListener;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    locationListener = new MyLocationListener();

    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener);
}
private class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener{

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        System.out.println("ZMIENIAMY SIĘ, zmieniamy siebie");
    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {

    }
}
}
```

Im using the newest android studio (intellij) with embedded (?) emulator. Phone is out of options.
ANd here what i've got:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main  
Process: com.example.szymon.gpslab1, PID: 3274  
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.szymon.gpslab1/com.example.szymon.gpslab1.MainActivity}: java.lang.SecurityException: "gps" location provider requires ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION permission.  

Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: "gps" location provider requires ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION permission.
```

I belive this is stupid mistake, but I've never like developed for android, im the javaman, and i've reached every tutorial on net, cant find answer.

Ah and y, I have location on in my emulator.

Comment: What version of Android are you testing on, and what is your `targetSdkVersion`?

Comment: I belive the default one. So minimal 15, max (target?) 23? But not sure. Tried changing it in androidmanifest using  <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="15" android:targetSdkVersion="15"/> did not help yet. Looking at AndroidEnthausiast answer now.

Comment: https://commonsware.com/blog/2015/08/31/hey-where-did-my-permission-go.html

Answer (score 25, accepted):

This is a common exception if your target SDK is 23 in your build.gradle.

Android 6.0 / sdk 23 introduces a new way of requesting permissions.

See the link below for how to handle permissions:

https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/index.html

Comment: Also check this one, which is specifically for Android 6.0 (API level 23): https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html